# Delete an item from Array List contact to Custom List View always delteing the latest one

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a custom list view, contains delete button and spinner (the spinner contain A-E characters).
And I have an issue with deleting the true row from my custom list view.

**Custom list view code:**

```
public class customListView extends BaseAdapter
{
    public Activity context;
    ArrayList<MyActivity.UserProperties> userPropertieses;
    public String[] spinnerValues;
    public LayoutInflater inflater;

    public  customListView(Activity context, ArrayList<MyActivity.UserProperties> userPropertieses, String[] spinnerArray)
    {
        super();
        this.context = context;
        this.userPropertieses = userPropertieses;
        spinnerValues = spinnerArray;
        this.inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() { return userPropertieses.size(); }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) { return null; }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) { return 0; }

    class ViewHolder
    {
        Button btnRemove;
        Spinner spinner;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup)
    {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (view == null)
        {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, null);

            holder.spinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
            holder.btnRemove = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.bu_Remove);

            // populate spinner
            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                    (view.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerValues);
            dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            holder.spinner.setFocusable(true);
            holder.spinner.requestFocus();
            holder.spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

            view.setTag(holder);

            // remove user implementation
            holder.btnRemove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Log.i("custom list view debug", "i = " + i);  // debug. verify i value is correct
                    ((MyActivity) context).deleteUser(i);
                }
            });

        }
        else
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

        return view;
    }
}
```

And my **main activity code** looks like this:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity
{
    ListView listView;
    ArrayList<UserProperties> userProperties = new ArrayList<UserProperties>();
    customListView adapter;
    SensorManager sensorManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);

        for (int i = 0; i<5; i++) {
            userProperties.add(new UserProperties());
        }

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        String[] spinnerValues = new String[] {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"};
        adapter = new customListView(MyActivity.this, userProperties, spinnerValues);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public void deleteUser (int index)
    {
        Log.i("debug", "Removing item " + index); // the index is really true and the true node deleting from the ArrayList but somehow the latest delete from the UI
        userProperties.remove(index);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

When I click on the `Remove` button `deleteUser` method called with the right index. but although the right node deleting from userProperties ArrayList somehow after `notiftDataSetChanged` is still alive
and the latest node delete.

So, how can I delete the right node/row (from the ArrayList and UI...)

**EDIT:**
Just to be clear, `i` variable contain true index. The true node deleted from the ArrayList. but something append after I called `notify` method. I prefer to stay with `BaseAdapter` and not implement `ArrayAdapter`.

**EDIT 2:**
After more debugging I found out my question was wrong. the true row really deleted just spinner values somehow update their values. I cannot close the question because it already answered.

Comment: `public class customListView extends BaseAdapter`. OMG!. Please do not call an adapter a listview. Use a better name for your own sake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
((MyActivity) context).deleteUser(i);
```

This line will always delete the first value from the `ListView`

You can use [CAB (contextual action bar)](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/selection.html)

See if the code helps you(it's basically a `ListActivity` with a custom adapter to hold the status of checked items(+ different background)):

```
public class CABSelection extends ListActivity {

    private ArrayList<String> mItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    private SelectionAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
            mItems.add("Name" + i);
        }
        // R.layout.adapters_cabselection_row is a LinearLayout(with green
        // background(#99cc00)) that wraps an ImageView and a TextView
        mAdapter = new SelectionAdapter(this,
                R.layout.adapters_cabselection_row, R.id.the_text, mItems);
        setListAdapter(mAdapter);
        getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
        getListView().setMultiChoiceModeListener(new MultiChoiceModeListener() {

            private int nr = 0;

            @Override
            public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
                inflater.inflate(R.menu.cabselection_menu, menu);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                Set<Integer> positions = mAdapter.getCurrentCheckedPosition();
                for (Integer pos : positions) {
                    sb.append(" " + pos + ",");
                }               
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.edit_entry:
                    Toast.makeText(CABSelection.this, "Edited entries: " + sb.toString(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case R.id.delete_entry:
                    Toast.makeText(CABSelection.this, "Deleted entries : " + sb.toString(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case R.id.finish_it:
                    nr = 0;
                    mAdapter.clearSelection();
                    Toast.makeText(CABSelection.this, "Finish the CAB!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    mode.finish();
                }
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
                nr = 0;
                mAdapter.clearSelection();
            }

            @Override
            public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode,
                    int position, long id, boolean checked) {
                if (checked) {
                    nr++;
                    mAdapter.setNewSelection(position, checked);                    
                } else {
                    nr--;
                    mAdapter.removeSelection(position);                 
                }
                mode.setTitle(nr + " rows selected!");

            }

        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        l.setItemChecked(position, !mAdapter.isPositionChecked(position));
    }

    private class SelectionAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

        private HashMap<Integer, Boolean> mSelection = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();

        public SelectionAdapter(Context context, int resource,
                int textViewResourceId, List<String> objects) {
            super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
        }

        public void setNewSelection(int position, boolean value) {
            mSelection.put(position, value);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        public boolean isPositionChecked(int position) {
            Boolean result = mSelection.get(position);
            return result == null ? false : result;
        }

        public Set<Integer> getCurrentCheckedPosition() {
            return mSelection.keySet();
        }

        public void removeSelection(int position) {
            mSelection.remove(position);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        public void clearSelection() {
            mSelection = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);//let the adapter handle setting up the row views
            v.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#99cc00")); //default color
            if (mSelection.get(position) != null) {
                v.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);// this is a selected position so make it red
            }
            return v;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just the latest row deleted and not the first. and your answer really works **but** Does I really need all this code to delete the right row? my `i` index is true and the right node deleted from the `ArrayList`...

Comment: Your i index is wrong to begin with. Just use a Toast to display the value and you will see.

Comment: @greenapps. but my `i` index is true! I print him with `Log` and is contain the true index.

Comment: Hmmm i have to rethink this... But you are removing an item from the userProperties which belongs to your activity. But you should remove it from the userProperties which belongs to your adapter. I cannot even believe that one item is deleted now from the listview. You could set a new adapter if you don't know how to remove it from the right list instead of a notify dataset changed.

Comment: i understand it's from you. sorry. delete my commnet

Answer (score 0):

Another way

```
adapter = new MyListAdapter(this);
lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
    AlertDialog.Builder adb=new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivity.this);
    adb.setTitle("Delete?");
    adb.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete " + position);
    final int positionToRemove = position;
    adb.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
    adb.setPositiveButton("Ok", new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            MyDataObject.remove(positionToRemove);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }});
    adb.show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 getView(final int i,
```

Do not make i final. You did that to use i in onClick(). But that is not possible. So remove the final. Add:

```
 holder.btnRemove.setTag(i);
```

And in onClick:

```
 int position = v.getTag(); 
 ..deleteUser(position);
```

Maybe you have to cast something somewhere..

Remark: You have to set the tag always. So do it just before `return view;`.

Please do not use an i for position.

Comment: Sorry, but not works. I added before `return view` `holder.btnRemove.setTag(i)` and in onClick method I change the call to `((MyActivity) context).deleteUser((Integer)holder.btnRemove.getTag())` and still the latest row deleted any time. Also, as I comment you, `i` contain true index and also the true node deleted. but for some reason the latest deleted, I don't know why...

Comment: I already told you in other comment to remove from the arraylist of the adapter instead of from the main activity's one. Meanwhile i have seen that the final i indeed works. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't saw your comment. I really saw in some examples on web people remove the node from the adapter but I cannot do this because I implement `BaseAdapter` and not `ArrayAdapter`. Do you think I must implement `ArrayAdapter` to do that? tnx

Comment: No. As i told you: "just set a new adapter" will do.

Comment: adapter.userProperties.remove(index); should work. And then do a notifyDatasetChanged. Please try.

Comment: Thanks, I try but it's not working :(. But thanks to you now I know I must implement `ArrayAdapter` (and not `BaseAdapter`) so really Thank you!

Comment: `it's not working` ?? That is no good description. What does not work? It should work if it compiles.